# Proof of the existence of a closest vector

Tags: general-topology

This post contains the prompt, my attempt at a proof and then a few questions about proving this using an alternate approach.

**Prompt**

Let $A$ be a convex, closed set on $R^L$ and let $z$ be a vector in $R^L \setminus C$. Prove: $\exists x^* \in C s.t. ||z-x^*|| \leq ||z-x||, \forall x \in C$

**Proof**:

To proceed by contradiction, assume: $\nexists x^* s.t.||z-x^*|| \leq ||z-x||, \forall x \in C$

$$ \implies \forall c \in C, \exists \epsilon > 0, y \in C, s.t. y \in B_{\epsilon}^C (x),  ||z-y|| \leq ||z-c|| $$
$$\implies a.) z \in C$$
$$\implies b.) \text{C is open}$$

In either case we have a contradiction. Thus,  $\exists x^* \in C s.t. ||z-x^*|| \leq ||z-x||, \forall x \in C$

**Questions**

1. Does this work as a proof? If not, how can I fix it?
2. We are provided the hint that $f(x):R^L \to R , f(x) = ||z-x||^2$ is continuous. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction to prove this directly using that hint?

Comment: Is the convex set $A$ or $C$?

Answer (score 1):

Using the hint: Fix $z\in \mathbb{R}^L\setminus C, x_0 \in C$ and consider the set
$$
S = \{y\in C : \|z-y\| \leq \|z-x_0\|\}
$$
Then $S$ is a closed (since $C$ is closed), bounded set (Check!) and hence compact. Now define $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(y) := \|z-y\|
$$
Then $f$ is continuous (by the hint), and hence attains a minimum at a point $x^{\ast} \in C$. This point $x^{\ast}$ clearly satisfies the required condition.

Comment: Is this set S bounded by $X_0$ and then the boundary of C?

Comment: A set must be bounded by a number - in this case that number is $\|z\| + \|z-x_0\|$. This follows from the triangle inequality.